# How to get raw hex values from pcap file?

Tags: python, parsing, hex, scapy, pcap

I've been playing around with scapy and want to read through and analyse every hex byte. So far I've been using scapy simply because I don't know another way currently. Before just writing tools myself to go through the pcap files I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it. Here's what I've done so far.

```py
packets = rdpcap('file.pcap')
tcpPackets = []
  for packet in packets:
    if packet.haslayer(TCP):
      tcpPackets.append(packet)
```

When I run `type(tcpPackets[0])` the type I get is:

```py
<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>
```

Then when I try to covert the Ether object into a string it gives me a mix of hex and ascii (as noted by the random parenthesis and brackets).

```py
str(tcpPackets[0])
```

```
"b'$\\xa2\\xe1\\xe6\\xee\\x9b(\\xcf\\xe9!\\x14\\x8f\\x08\\x00E\\x00\\x00[:\\xc6@\\x00@\\x06\\x0f\\xb9\\n\\x00\\x01\\x04\\xc6)\\x1e\\xf1\\xc0\\xaf\\x07[\\xc1\\xe1\\xff0y<\\x11\\xe3\\x80\\x18 1(\\xb8\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x08\\n8!\\xd1\\x888\\xac\\xc2\\x9c\\x10%\\x00\\x06MQIsdp\\x03\\x02\\x00\\x05\\x00\\x17paho/34AAE54A75D839566E'"
```

I have also tried using hexdump but I can't find a way to parse through it.

Comment: `str(...)` here probably just confuses you, because it converts your bytes string/stream into a text representation with the `b` still in the start. Instead, do `tcpPackets[0].decode('hex')`. An example would be `str(b'moo')` will become `"b'moo'"` when in fact it's `b'moo'` to begin with, but as a representation (to tell you) that it's a bytes string, `str()` will "honor" and keep the bytes indicator there so you can understand the data type better (very loosely described).

Comment: @Torxed .decode (or in 3.7 I'm using ```codec.decode()```) doesn't work because it doesn't take scrapy Ether() objects, only byte-like object. And I can't seem to find a way to convert Ether() to anytype of object instead str().

Comment: I see, I didn't know it was a `scapy.layers.l2.Ether` instance, I thought you managed to extract the raw representation of the ethernet frame as the data suggested. But in that case, you probably aught to use `packet.dst` or `packet.src` instead. Or try the some what nasty hack I references to below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the proper dupe now, but this is just a miss-use/miss-understanding of `str()`. The original data is in a bytes format, for instance `x = b'moo'`.

When `str()` retrieves your bytes string, it will do so by calling the `__str__` function of the `bytes` class/object. That will return a representation of itself. The representation will keep `b` at the beginning because it's believed to distinguish and make it easier for humans to understand that it's a bytes object, as well as avoid encoding issues I guess *(alltho that's speculations)*.

Same as if you tried accessing `tcpPackets[0]` from a terminal, it would call `__repr__` and show you something like `<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>` most likely.

As an example code you can experiment with, try this out:

```
class YourEther(bytes):
    def __str__(self):
        return '<Made Up Representation>'

print(YourEther())
```

Obviously scapy's returns another representation, not just a static string that says "made up representation". But you probably get the idea.

So in the case of `<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>` it's `__repr__` or `__str__` function probably returns `b'$\\xa2\\.......` instead of just it's default class representation *(some correction here might be in place tho as I don't remember/know all the technical namification of the behaviors)*.

As a workaround, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513373/searching-for-hex-in-scapy-packet) might fix your issue:

```
hexlify(str(tcpPackets[0]))
```

All tho you probably have to account for the prepended `b'` as well as trailing `'` and remove those accordingly. *(Note: `"` won't be added in the beginning or end, those are just a second representation in your console when printing. They're not actually there in terms of data)*

Scapy is probably more intended to use `tcpPackets[0].dst` rather than grabing the raw data. But I've got very little experience with Scapy, but it's an abstraction layer for a reason and it's probably hiding the raw data or it's in the core docs some where which I can't find right now.

More info on the `__str__` description: [Does python `str()` function call `__str__()` function of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168899/does-python-str-function-call-str-function-of-a-class)

Last note, and that is if you actually want to access the raw data, it seams like you can access it with the [Raw](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html#scapy.packet.Raw) class: [Raw load found, how to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293209/pythonscapy-raw-load-found-how-to-access)

Comment: Note on python 3 (which is the case here), you should be doing `bytes(pkt)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the bytes of a packet into a `numpy` array as follows:

```py
for p in tcpPackets:
    raw_pack_data = np.frombuffer(p.load, dtype = np.uint8)
    # Manipulate the bytes stored in raw_pack_data as you like.
```

This is fast. In my case, `rdpcap` takes ~20 times longer than putting all the packets into a big array in a similar `for` loop for a 1.5GB file.